# Need Help in switching values in a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers, such as:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to switch the first 2 items of the list with the last 2, or the first 3 with the last 3, and so on.

When i assign the values of the 1st two numbers to the last 2 items of the list, i then cannot assign the last 2 values **(what used to be the last 2 values of the list)** to the first two because the last 2 values have been lost.

If i try using another empty list and **appending the last 2 values of the original list** to that list, **then appending the middle values**, and then the **first 2 values** of the old list, I end up with something like this:

```
[[[5, 6], [3, 4], [1, 2]]]
```

**I don't want nested lists!** What I want is:

```
[5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: you're almost there with the second approach, except that you should `extend` the target rather than `append` to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> nums[:2], nums[-2:] = nums[-2:], nums[:2]
>>> nums
[5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

This modifies the original list but if you want a separate new list you should use the following:

```
>>> nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> swapped_nums = nums[-2:] + nums[2:-2] + nums[:2]
>>> swapped_nums
[5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

**Note:** This won't work properly if your list has < 4 elements